# Is there possibility for registering URLs or domains in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to register Authorized URLs in Google Maps via an API?

Currently, I am manually adding URLs through the Google Maps Support portal, but I would like to be able to make an API call when a customer submits a new domain to my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to manage API key restrictions programatically.

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make it possible:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829646

Please star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications, at the moment it has only 6 stars, not enough to increase its visibility.

#### Update from Google

> The best way to handle thousands of authorized domains is to use an API to programmatically manage your API Keys and their restrictions, and we have recently launched a new service that allows you to do this.
>
> This API is still in Alpha. If you are interested in becoming a Trusted Tester for this service, you can use the following form to sign up, please read the instructions carefully:
>   https://forms.gle/qx2SMcarWCAsbWVp7
>
> Please note that this API is not part of the Google Maps Platform. After you fill out the form, you will be contacted by the API Keys API team with instructions on how to get started, and how to receive support.
>
> API Keys API is currently free of charge. However, please note that use of Cloud Endpoints may be subject to charges at high traffic volume. You can check the pricing sheet here:
>   https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/pricing-and-quotas