# Using google key on multiple domains

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

we have a function using some of the API-keys from google maps, but we have around 10k+ domains (domains, not subdomains),

we know there is an option to set up and enable a domain each at a time, but it's very time-consuming.

Is there any way to automate this, so we can add to our system a way to quickly enable and disable domains without going through the Google interface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there possibility for registering URLs or domains in Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730802/is-there-possibility-for-registering-urls-or-domains-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: @MrUpsidown sir, I disagree with you, I'm specifically asking for a way to manipulate this from the api coding an answer to solve this, I tagged the official google maps because that's how google handle this now on their official website. but thanks for commenting

Comment: @xomena yes it's seems to be the same issue, it seems it had been open and never closed for almost 2 years and a half now, I guess I will open a bounty or contact somebody at google directly unless you know any solution :S?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no programmatical solution for your issue at the moment. We should wait and hope that Google will implement the feature request one day.